# OnNetworkDisconnected player event is not being launched on my Samsung 2013 TV

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

This is the documentation of this event: http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00011/deviceapi_player_onnetworkdisconnected.html, but I've realized that the device API where this documentation is contained is only for 2011 and 2012 devices. Does somebody know if this event has been removed for 2013 devices?

Comment: Since 2013 devices have moved to WebKit, I'd speculate that it has been replaced by [`navigate.onLine`](http://caniuse.com/#search=onLine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OnNetworkDisconnected is working fine on 2013.